# Unity 5.5 Standard Asset ParticleSystems throwing TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tls1.2, particle-system

This TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD error occurs whenever I add some certain Unity Standard Particle System assets prefab for example Fireworks and Explosion in the Scene. It also generates a huge amount of log messages that states "Allocation of 752 bytes at 0524a60f", "Allocation of 22960 bytes at 0542a6f0" (more like that). It also creates a huge lag and drops the FPS incredibly.

I have used Particle Systems for example Flare, Dust Storm and AfterBurner the whole time in my project and they worked as expected. However some particle systems like Explosion and Fire didn't work perfectly both in the scene and in the game view. The individual simulation of the child particle systems of the Explosion and Fire prefab worked perfectly in the Scene view but the same prefabs simulate weirdly in the game.

I am using Unity 5.5 and this "TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD error" should have been fixed in 5.4.0 b23 but apparently its not. How do I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I just solved reimporting the assets. Just use the Reimport All option in Asset menu.

Comment: Thanks... but it didn't work. Same as before. Which version are you using currently?